# Going through a loop with an angle

Tags: java

I want to change the direction of a loop with an angle.

I think it has to look like this:

```
while(y < someValue){
    doSomething(x,y);
    x = x + Math.sin(x);
    y++;
}
```

I want to use this to draw a line with an angle from a point (0,0) for example (but I don't want to use the java.awt.drawLine()).
If the angle is 90°, `x` would stay 0 and `y` would increment for every iteration by 1. For 45° both `x` and `y` would be incremented by 1 for every iteration and so on.

Which operation do I have to use to increment y?
I just guessed it has to do something with `sin(x)` or `cos(x)`.

Comment: This has a lot more to do with trig than with programming.

Comment: If `x` is the x coordinate, then it isn't an angle and you should not be using `Math.sin()` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

given an angle, your ratio of len(x) to len(y) is cos(angle) : sin(angle)

So, in this intance, you need to increment `x` by cos(angle) and `y` by sin(angle)

Make sure they are both of type `double` since cos and sin will can be less than one!

Comment: More precisely, he should be incrementing `x` by `r*cos(angle)` and `y` by `r*sin(angle)` for some constant `r` which depends on exactly how his drawing works--for example, what's the scale of his drawing, does 1 on an axis correspond to 1 pixel or something less or more.  But setting `r=1` should be good enough to get him started.

Comment: Good point. However, the loop could be re-worked such that it incrementally adds up to r. They were very specific that they couldnt use drawLine(), so my guess is it needs to be incremental